# Using two separate objects, I would like to return an object with the matching key, value pairs?

Tags: javascript

I have created three `functions`, that can make two separate `arrays` with the matching `keys` and the matching `properties`. I would like to use those two `arrays` to create a new `object` with all of the matching pairs. Below I included the `functions` I have so far.

I am a beginner in `Javascript` ( which is most likely already apparent) so if you can explain each step thoroughly and not get to complex I would greatly appreciate it.

```js
function contains(array, obj_to_check){
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
  if (array[i] == obj_to_check) {
   return true;
  }
 } 
}
function sharedKeys(obj1, obj2) {
 var obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1);
 var obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2);
 var sharedArray = [];
 for( var x = 0; x < obj1Keys.length; x++){
  if (contains(obj2Keys, obj1Keys[x])){
  sharedArray.push(obj1Keys[x]);
  }
 }
 return sharedArray;
}
function sharedProperties(obj1, obj2) {
 var obj1Props = [];
 var obj2Props = [];
 var propertiesArray = [];
 for(var i in obj1)
  obj1Props.push(obj1[i]);
 for(var x in obj2)
  obj2Props.push(obj2[x]);
 for (var y = 0; y < obj1Props.length; y ++){
  if(contains(obj1Props, obj2Props[y])){
   propertiesArray.push(obj2Props[y])
  }
 }
 return propertiesArray;
}
```

Comment: When a match is found, create a object. For example, you `.push` when a match is found, but you can `create an object as well.

Comment: Some example input and an example of the desired output from that input would be helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing two objects, not two values. The only way that your == comparison works here is if both of them refer to the same object. You need to check and see if every properties and fields of those two objects are equal. Besides, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) about comparison in JavaScript.

Comment: I think the best way to compare to objects equity in JavaScript is by converting them to JSON string. Json Stringify will do the work for you.

Comment: JSON.stringify turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

JSON.parse turns a string of JSON text into a Javascript object.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not a safe way to compare objects because it doesn't iterate properties in any well-defined order. Even if you called it passing the same object, `JSON.stringify` is not guaranteed to always return the same result (but it will on most implementations, yes).

Comment: Good point. @Oriol. Maybe it's better to have a primary key (surrogate key) on each object and only compare that. Anyway. It's completely design decision.